# Can I check modelstate without modelbinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, data-annotations

I'm getting my feet wet with the Entity Framework and am wondering if there is a way for me to check model state without model binding happening.

Say I create a user primarily from code, is there a way for me to check to make sure it is valid according to my predefined data annotations before I update?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = "test";
        u.Password = "test";
        u.Email = "test";

        DefaultContext db = new DefaultContext();            

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(u);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Response.Write(u.Id);
        }
        else
            // model is not valid

        return View();
    }
```

The above code does not work because there is no binding happening. Or maybe I am confused of the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ModelState won't be available because it's set up by the model binder.  The ModelBinder didn't bind a model so it didn't run validation thus ModelState will be empty.

But that doesn't stop you from using attributes and performing validation.

Assuming you are using the DataAnnotation attributes, you can run the validation without model binding.

Given this class:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

You can do this:

```
        var widget = new Widget
                        {
                            Id = 12,
                            Price = 15.57M
                        };

        var context = new ValidationContext(widget, null, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if( Validator.TryValidateObject( widget, context, results, true ) )
        {
            //Validation Successful
        }
        else
        {
            //Validation Failed
        }
```

The Name property was not set and the TryValidateObject() will fail.  The results collection will have the actual error that occurred.

Comment: I learn something new every time I come here.  I wasn't aware of the ValidateModel() function - Jayantha's answer is also correct and much easier if you're using ASP.Net MVC.  The answer I gave will work outside the context of a controller.

Comment: The above works very nicely when validating a model without submitting a form, in which case the `TryValidateModel` fails: `When a model is being validated, all validators for all properties are run if at least one form input is bound to a model property.` From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 11):

you can use `TryValidateModel`    or `ValidateModel`

```
 User u = new User();
    u.Username = "test";
    u.Password = "test";
    u.Email = "test";


    if (TryValidateModel(u))
     {

     }else{

     }
```